# Tsql where value is in json array (any index)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In MS SQL server, I have the following JSON :

```
[{      "name": "John",      "skills": ["SQL", "C#", "Azure"]  }, {      "name": "Jane",      "surname": "Doe"  }]
```

Stored in field in table. What i want to do is to check if Name = John no matter of the level.
If i use query like :

```
WHERE JSON_VALUE(ColumnName, '$[0].name') = 'John'
```

It's working , but i don't know if John is on index 0, it could be on index 1 , so i want to make it for ANY position. Basically what i want to accomplish is to return value no matter of the index, if John exist somewhere - that's ok

I've tried like :

```
WHERE JSON_VALUE(ColumnName, '$.name') = 'John'
```

or

```
WHERE JSON_VALUE(ColumnName, '$[].name') = 'John'
```

But obviously that is not the right way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`OPENJSON` with the `WITH` clause is a nice way of shredding JSON (if sometimes perhaps overly elaborate).

```
DECLARE @t TABLE(j NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT @T(j) VALUES (N'[{      "name": "John",      "skills": ["SQL", "C#", "Azure"]  }, {      "name": "Jane",      "surname": "Doe"  }]')

SELECT * FROM @t WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM OPENJSON(j) 
    WITH (
        [name] NVARCHAR(100)
    ) 
    WHERE [name] = 'John'
)
```

Note that the whole subquery with `EXISTS` is necessary to prevent the query from returning the same row multiple times if the row contains more than one `John`. If you actually *want* the row multiple times, use `CROSS APPLY`.